# iOS Unable to install ipa on iPad afer upgrading to iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, installation, ipa

I'm having a strange problem while installing ipa on my iPad with iOS version 7.1.2. I've upgraded my iPad to 7.1.2, and now I'm trying to install my ipa on iPad, but it gets stuck while installing, although it is not proceeding anyway. When I installed a provisioning certificate to the iPad first, and then installed ipa, it did work. I'm not able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: try to download again provisional cer of dev after edit add youar all device is check or not. and then use it.

Comment: Did you do a factory reset? If that's the case you need to install the provisioning again.

Comment: Hi Nitin thanks for your reply, I have already created new provisioning profile but still it is giving error.